# selenium fileupload win+linux

Tags: file-upload, selenium, cross-platform

I have some seleniumtest
they include a fileupload

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=input.rf-fu-inp</td>
    <td>C:\seleniumtestresources\user.csv</td>
</tr>
```

now the tests must run under a linux environment (suse 12.1). Has anybody an idea how to define the path that he is working on both plattforms?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problems.

I am running my test cases on Selenium Grid and I am programmatically replacing / with \ and vice versa depending on what OS is running on a node.

There is no format that works for both win and linux as far as I know.

Comment: do u execute it with javacode or java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -userExtensions user-extensions.js -htmlSuite "*firefox"

Comment: I run it in java from a TestNG suite.